# Why unreached try-catch block increase Runtime time?

Tags: c++, try-catch

I'm currently creating my own container Lib, but I've seen that unreachable(invalidated if statement) `try-catch` block increased runtime time.
So here is my test,

`Vector.cpp :`

```
template<class Type, class Allocator >
void vector<Type, Allocator >::push_back(Type&& ObjectToPushBack)
{
    if (_capacity == _size)
    {
#if 1
        try
        {
            emplace_back(std::move(ObjectToPushBack));
        }
        catch (NullException& n)
        {
            std::cout << n.what() << std::endl;
            throw n;
        }
#endif
    }
    else
        emplace_back_no_except(std::move(ObjectToPushBack));
}
```

`Main.cpp :`

```
int _cdecl main()
{
    ctn::vector<TYPE> myvec;

    Timer t;

    myvec.reserve(NB);

    auto f = [&]() {for (int i = 0; i < NB; ++i)myvec.push_back(TYPE());};

    t.timeThisFunction(f, ("My Vector Push Back " + std::to_string(NB) + " 
    Elements").c_str());
}
```

`NB` is 10000000 and `Type` is int.

`reserve` function act like the in the `std`.

`Timer` is a little lib that I've created to measure time easily , it overload `std::chrono`.

The average time with the `try-catch` block is ~70ms and with the block commented, ~18ms, this is a big gap between the two.

So, I want to know why this `try-catch` block increase the time without being reached( the `_capacity` equal the `_size` only after the final push), Is the compilator(MSVC 2017) pre-allocate `try-catch` block on the stack, even if unused ?

NB : if you want the Visual Studio 2017 Solution, i can send it to you.

Comment: No more than an educated guess, but I'd say it's affecting inlining, so without the `try`-`catch` it's compiled without a real function call, but with it, it really does make a function call.

Comment: So I've tried with `_forceinline` before the `push_back` declaration, but it does not change anything, it's still ~70ms. So i don't know if I've done it correctly to test your hypothesis, i know that just `inline` is an hint for the compilator, but `_forceinline` must inline the function, even if the compilator does not agree.

Comment: There are times when `_forceinline` still doesn't inline, though I'm very rusty on what those are. I'd try the opposite, and use `/Ob0` when compiling to turn off all inlining.

Comment: I've tried the opposite and now the gap is less visible, but still there, ~135ms without the `try-catch` and ~150ms with it. So it's may be one factor of the big gap, but something else occur i think, because there is still a gap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add in a `try`/`catch` block, the compiler adds in code to support exceptions.  This is executed in the function header (along with the code to allocate space for local variables and save registers).  With MSVC, some of the exception support that is executed appears to consist of setting a global variable to point to the local exception data, saving the previous value of this pointer, initializing a local variable to indicate which try/catch block in the function is active, and setting up another local variable that points to a table of exception handlers.

The active index is updated whenever a try block is entered or exited.

Other compilers can have different ways to handle exceptions.