# C++ function performance issue

Tags: c++, string, performance, function, visual-c++

I met a C++ function performance issue, testing with the code below. The implementations of the `queryInterface` and `queryInterface1` are almost same. The only difference is that `queryInterface` calling `classType` function, and `classType` function calling `classType1`, `queryInterface1` call `classType1` directly. The performance of `queryInterface1` is bad, it takes twice times as long as `queryInterface`. What's the problem of `queryInterface1`, and Why? Compiled with MSVC. See the output in console：

> time cost of queryInterface(): 2453
>
> time cost of queryInterface1(): 4961

```
#include <string>
#include <time.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;

namespace
{
    int find(const string& name)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    class A
    {
    public:
        static int classType();
        static int classType1();
        virtual void* queryInterface(int id) const
        {
            if (A::classType() == id)
                return const_cast<A*>(this);

            return nullptr;
        }
        virtual void* queryInterface1(int id) const
        {
            if (A::classType1() == id)
                return const_cast<A*>(this);

            return nullptr;
        }
    };

    int A::classType()
    {
        static int s_classType = classType1();
        return s_classType;
    }

    int A::classType1()
    {
        static int s_classType = find("A");
        return s_classType;
    }
}

int main()
{
    clock_t start, stop;
    const size_t count = 1000000000;

    A* pA = new A;
    start = clock();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        pA->queryInterface(A::classType());
    }
    stop = clock();
    cout << "time cost of queryInterface(): " << stop - start << endl;

    start = clock();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
         pA->queryInterface1(A::classType1());
    }
    stop = clock();
    cout << "time cost of queryInterface1(): " << stop - start << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How did you compile it? Did you enable optimization? `find("A")` requires `std::string` object creation, that makes this call slower.

Comment: You did run each version more than once?

Comment: FWIW, I don't see that pattern with g++ 6.4.0 under cygwin.

Comment: @S.M., The optimization option is set to "Maximize Speed (/O2)". Both should call find("A") once, because it's called by static variable.

Comment: @John3136, Yes, I run them 1000000000 times.

Comment: @RSahu, I built the code with MS build, is it as MS build issue?

Comment: @ldlchina, I don't have any idea. If I were you, I wouldn't put too much weight on these numbers.

Comment: You may look at https://godbolt.org/g/eHNSV2 to see differences.

Comment: @S.M., I have few knowledge about ASM, dose it mean the string is construct and destroyed everytime call in A::classType1? Thanks.

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47244407/why-unreached-try-catch-block-increase-runtime-time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The performance difference is due to the compiler setting up security checks within the call of `A::classType1`.  These are set up every call, even though it is only be really needed for the one time the `find` function is called.

The security checks determine if the stack has been overwritten, potentially clobbering the stack frame, including the return address.

Changing the initial value if `s_classType` to be a constant integer, instead of the call to `find`, results in a much faster execution of the `queryInterface1` calls.

The security checks can be disabled with the `/GS-` compiler option.

Comment: Do you mean change the A::classType1 as bellow? It is not better.    int A::classType1()
    {
        static int s_classType = -1;
        if (s_classType == -1)
        {
            s_classType = find("A");
        }
        return s_classType;
    }

Comment: @ldlchina No, I eliminated the call to `find` completely (`static int s_classType = 17;`).  You'll need to put the call to `find` into another function to avoid the exception handler penalty.

Comment: Likes A:classType? If so, that make me nervous, when need to do so? what is the rule? Thanks. @1201ProgramAlarm

Comment: @ldlchina Yes, like `A::classType`.  You'd want to do that if the static initializer expression does something that may need an exception handler when the rest of the function does not.

Comment: Why does this not happen for `A::classType() ` ?

Comment: @GauravSehgal Because `A::classType` doesn't have to deal with exceptions.  Nothing within the function has a destructor that needs to be called, and there's nothing to clean up if an exception passes by.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm But What needs to be cleaned/destructed in `classType1();`? And internally `classType();` does call `classType1();` so shouldn't it behave the same?

Comment: `classType1()` constructs a `string` for the parameter to `find`; `classType()` does not.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm AAh..Thanks. and just the last thing, why the exception handler not inserted within `classType1();` when `classType1();` is called from `classType();`

Comment: If you declare `find(const char *name)`, then `A::classType1` would not have to deal with exceptions.

Comment: No this has nothing to do with the fact there is an exception frame, exception frames do not interact with code on the normal path. This is just that std::string has no constexpr constructors.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm， Thanks. How to check if there is exception handler inserted in a function?

Comment: @Oliv The Microsoft compiler sets up the exception frame on function entry on every call.  It doesn't wait for coming across code in the function that needs it.  You can inspect the generated assembly code to see this.

Comment: @GauravSehgal The exception handler is inserted, but `classType1()` is only called once from `classType()`, so the exception frame is only set up once.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Since he did not explicitly cite MSVC and just talked about C++ I thought he was using a good quality implementation!!!

Comment: @Oliv Early revisions of OP's question had `#include "stdafx.h"`, which is a dead giveaway that it is MSVC.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm I would still have done the mistake, actualy I thought new versions of MSVC used a more modern exception managment (as the one of the gABI, or better is possible too!)

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm, I saw "__security_check_cookie" in the  assembly code in https://godbolt.org/g/eHNSV2, is that added for exception handler?

Comment: @ldlchina I misread the disassembly.  Further investigation shows me the actual issue.  I've updated the answer.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm, Right, Thanks.